# How to recover replaced files in local Git repository after pull request?

Tags: github, git-shell

Originally on my Github are some outdated `styles.css` and JavaScript files and others.

I was working on my project last night but didn't push it to Github or back it up. It was just saved in my local repository using a series of local, unpushed commits.

Being a newbie that I am, I did a `git pull request master`, and all the files in my local repository got replaced with the original `styles.css` and JavaScript that was in my github.

Is there a way to get those files back?

I did a git `reset head@{2}` where I believe the state of the repository before the pull request was, and it showed some unstaged files.

In Gitshell my command line has "master [+10 ~19 -42 !]" with the text master being yellow.

At this point, what do I do? Currently I seem to have lost a lot of work.

Comment: Did you do any commits in your local repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have performed commits often you can pretty much get to any of them.

Use `git reflog` first (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog). It will show you all the interim commits you've made. Once you find a relevant one you can do `git reset #commit_id`.

Comment: I did a git add and then commit just before the pull request while in gh-pages, not master (forgot to do git checkout master before I closed git shell previously) , and doing a git reflow show, it shows the commit. But when I go to Github.com and navigate to gh-pages, it doesn't show and the files in gh-pages were still the old version.

Comment: What do I type after doing a reset? Currently the master text is yellow in git shell. I don't wanna go any further on my own

Comment: If you can see the changes reflected on your local machine (it is up to date) you can push the changes to github by doing git push --force. Otherwise please clarify what the expected endresult is.

Comment: I have fixed it now by doing what you suggested. Do a "git reflog show" to see where I last made a commit. Then using git reset HEAD`{2`} in gitshell. Then I typed "git status" to show which files were modified and deleted. This is the part where I was stuck, not knowing how to get the files in the "git status" list back to my local repository. Googled it and found a solution. It's "git checkout -- ." to recover all the files in the "git status" list back to the local repository. All files on github was left untouched, only the ones that I pulled to my local were recovered.